# kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out when trying to connect to Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a Pi running Octoprint. I've tried to configure as many things as I can using config files (having it on port 23, etc), but it still isn't working. On my client, I type this:

```
PS C:\Users\uahs> ssh -vvv -p 23 pi@10.230.141.43
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.230.141.43 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 10.230.141.43 [10.230.141.43] port 23.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\uahs/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\uahs/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\uahs/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\uahs/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\uahs/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\uahs/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\uahs/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\uahs/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/uahs/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\uahs/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug3: recv - from CB(2) ERROR:138, io:000002460156D400
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out
```

The errors about failing to open certificates are normal. I have a certificate already in place.

Here is the server's `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Jul  6 16:22:50 octopi su: (to pi) root on none
Jul  6 16:22:50 octopi su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Jul  6 16:22:50 octopi sshd[728]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
Jul  6 16:22:50 octopi sshd[728]: debug1: Bind to port 23 on 0.0.0.0.
Jul  6 16:22:50 octopi sshd[728]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 23.
Jul  6 16:22:50 octopi sshd[728]: debug1: Bind to port 23 on 10.230.141.43.
Jul  6 16:22:50 octopi sshd[728]: error: Bind to port 23 on 10.230.141.43 failed: Address already in use.
Jul  6 16:22:50 octopi systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Jul  6 16:33:53 octopi sshd[728]: debug1: Forked child 1288.
Jul  6 16:33:53 octopi sshd[1288]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Jul  6 16:33:53 octopi sshd[1288]: debug1: rexec start in 4 out 4 newsock 4 pipe 6 sock 7
Jul  6 16:33:53 octopi sshd[1288]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Jul  6 16:33:53 octopi sshd[1288]: Connection from 10.230.19.79 port 56747 on 10.230.141.43 port 23
Jul  6 16:35:19 octopi sshd[728]: debug1: Forked child 2296.
Jul  6 16:35:19 octopi sshd[2296]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Jul  6 16:35:19 octopi sshd[2296]: debug1: rexec start in 4 out 4 newsock 4 pipe 7 sock 8
Jul  6 16:35:19 octopi sshd[2296]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Jul  6 16:35:19 octopi sshd[2296]: Connection from 10.230.19.79 port 56784 on 10.230.141.43 port 23
Jul  6 16:41:26 octopi sshd[728]: debug1: Forked child 6567.
Jul  6 16:41:26 octopi sshd[6567]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Jul  6 16:41:26 octopi sshd[6567]: debug1: rexec start in 4 out 4 newsock 4 pipe 6 sock 7
Jul  6 16:41:26 octopi sshd[6567]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Jul  6 16:41:26 octopi sshd[6567]: Connection from 10.230.19.79 port 57048 on 10.230.141.43 port 23
```

The web interface works just fine, and I know it recognizes there's an SSH server there. What can I do to fix this? Is this a network problem or a configuration problem?

I tried to ssh into it with the port I configured and the known IP address. I expected it to connect (it had connected perfectly a few months ago), but it just timed out.

Comment: `error: Bind to port 23 on 10.230.141.43 failed: Address already in use`.  Can you do a `netstat -ltpn4` on the server side and see if you don't already have a service (telnet?) running on port 23.

Comment: I checked and it does not appear so. It's an open port.

Comment: What's the output of `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -o ListenAddress=10.230.141.43:23` on the raspberry Pi, as root?